# On-the-fly conversion of FLAC to MP3 when syncing with Android?

Tags: android, music, rhythmbox, conversion, flac

I have a large collection of FLAC music files which I would like to sync to my Android phone.  However, the FLAC files are very large...and before I bother to create a seperate MP3 music library it occurred to me that there may be a way to get Rythmbox (or some other app) to convert them as part of the syncing process.

I've read that iTunes automatically converts ALAC files to M4A lossy format during syncs...is there a way to do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to do nothing - it Just Works.

Just plug the phone into the computer with the USB connection on Android set to "Disk Drive".  Set up the sync in Rythmbox and then sync.

Wish I had some control over the transcoding, but at least they're compressed from FLAC to M4As by default.